# Cannot add jar files into server classpath in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jar, classpath, eclipse-kepler

I cannot add jar files into server classpath through eclipse (kepler version), here follows the senario i used
1. Opened the launch configuration of server by clicking **Open launch configuration** link
[image]
2. Added the jar files to classpath from **Classpath** tab. Then applied and save it by clicking Ok button.
[image]

But when i take this configuration tab again i cant find out any jar files previously added.

Comment: You shouldn't add jars to the server classpath. The jars should be in your deployed war file, under WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: @JBNizet Then what is the use of this option in eclipse?

Comment: Eclipse allows you to do it, but that doesn't mean you should. Just like Java allows you to put classes in the default package, although you should almost always not do it. The jars of your webapp should be packaged with your webapp. You shouldn't change the classpath of the whole JBoss server for a specific webapp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Argumments tab you can see  a check box with label as "ALways update arguments related to the runtime". Make sure that check box is unchecked. Guess that will do it :)

Regards

Ajin